# Unity: Running code on the "Create Other" menu?

Tags: unity

Right now I am trying to create a `TextMesh` `GameObject` from code.

The graphics primitives are accessible through `PrimitiveTypes`, I'm thinking there must be something similar, and if not, I could at least run whatever static function is bound to the menu - if only I knew the name.

The more general question is "how one get at all the other items on the "Create Other" without using the menu itself?"

Comment: What do you mean by "running code" on a menu? You mean you want to create those prefabs via code?

Comment: @Byte56 I intended it to be read `[Running] [code on the “Create Other” menu]`, rather than `[Running code on] [the “Create Other” menu]`. My bad, it's far from clear. Optimally, I would like to be able to call the method which that menu-clicking would. Whilst I do wish to create the same prefabs, I'd really like to know exactly what is going on when I select one of the builtin items from this menu.